# Снова об однокоренных словах

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Меч" и "метать"? Или они только кажутся похожими?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меч-существительное м.р., холодное оружие.
Метать - глагол неопр.формы,образовано от существительного "метание". Существительное ср.р.
Следовательно, это неоднокоренные слова.

Answer (score 0):

[**МЕЧ**](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87)

От праслав. формы *mеčь, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. мечь (др.-греч. ξίφος, μάχαιρα; Клоц., Супр., Мар., Зогр.), русск. меч, укр. мíч, белор. меч, болг. меч, словенск. mèč (род. п. méča), чешск., словацк. mеč, польск. miecz, в.-луж. mječ, н.-луж. mjас. Почти все слав. языки отражают праслав. *mеčь, только сербохорв. ма̏ч (род. п. ма̀ча) восходит к *mьčь. Это слово уже давно объясняют как заимств. из готск. *mēkeis -- то же, засвидетельствованного в виде формы вин. п. ед. в готск.  (mēki), др.-исл. mækir, др.-англ. méсе, др.-сакс. mâki, откуда и финск. miekka "меч". При такой этимологии представляют затруднение краткие гласные в слав., кроме того, герм. слово лишено достоверных родственных связей. Предполагали связь с лат. mасtō, -ārе "убить, зарезать", сближали также с ирл. machtaim, но последнее, вероятно, заимств. из лат.; недостоверно и родство со ср.-перс. magēn "меч". Допустимо заимствование слав. и готск. слов из неизвестного, общего источника, при этом обязательным в нем было наличие k; ср. груз. maẋva "острый, меч", удинск. mеẋ "серп", лезг. mаẋ "железо", однако следует заметить, что вокализм этих слов опять-таки представляет трудности. Приводимые в качестве источника Г. Шмидтом дидойск., капуч. mаč᾽а "сабля", куанад. mīčа "кинжал" не объясняют готск. k. Вероятно, они могли быть заимств. из слова мечь через тюрк. (ср. тур. mäč) из слав. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы. Предполагается также связь с кельтск. mecc- «сверкать, блестеть» (мечи обрабатывались огнём). Использованы данные Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов (2007); см. Список литературы.

[**МЕТАТЬ**](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. метѫ, мести, мештѫ, метати (др.-греч. βάλλειν), укр. мечу́, мета́ти, болг. ме́тна «брошу, накину», сербохорв. ме̏ħе̑м, мѐтати «бросать, кидать, подавать», словенск. métem, mésti, mẹ́čem, mẹ́tati — то же, др.-чешск. metu, mésti, чешск. metám, metati «бросать», польск. miotam, miotać — то же, в.-луж. mjetać, н.-луж. mjataś, полаб. mесе «швыряет». Родственно лит. metù, mèsti «бросать», латышск. mętu, mest, др.-прусск. metis «бросок, метание», лит. šáukštо mẽtas «полная ложка», латышск. mets «куча зерна». Далее допускают родство с мету́, при условии исходного знач. «крутиться, бросать»; с другой ступенью вокализма — мота́ть. Кроме того, пытаются установить родственную связь с терминами «мерить», ср. лит. išmèsti «вымерять», mãtas, mãstas, mẽstas «мера», matúoti «мерить», алб. mаs «мерю», mаtеm «мечу, целюсь», лат. mētior «мерю», причем ссылаются на наличие знач. названий мер длины, развившиеся из названий броска. Сюда же, по мнению этимолога Френкеля, лит. matýti «смотреть», русск. смотреть, т. е. первонач. «бросать взгляды». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

**ВЫВОД**

Итак, слова однокоренными не являются, происхождение у них разное.